# How to completely suppress output of a command?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, redirect

I want this command to work silently,

```
echo "any_password" | sudo -S true
```

I tried redirecting the output of stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`. When I provide the correct password it works as expected, but when the password is incorrect I still see some error on the screen.

```
echo "incorrect_password" | sudo -S true > /dev/null 2>&1
```

gives,

```
Sorry, try again.
```

The output was only partially suppressed. Is there a way to suppress it completely?

Comment: Try `echo foo | sudo -S true &> /dev/null` However I can't reproduce it!

Comment: I have tried it already, it doesn't work. Btw isn't this command the same as mine, just written differently(although mine is portable)?

Comment: Yes it is... as I said I can't reproduce it even with your command! try something like this: `echo foo | sudo -S true > stdout 2> stderr` check and see what is happening. what are the contents of these two file and what is going to be printed out on your terminal.

Comment: @Ravexina why aren't you able to reproduce it?
Here's the output of stderr
 ` [sudo] password for akash: [sudo] password for akash: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
  `
stdout is empty and I am still seeing 'Sorry try again' on my screen

Comment: By "I can't reproduce it" I mean that it's working perfectly fine for me...

Comment: ohh, that's strange.

Comment: The password will ALWAYS show in `ps -ef` so please don't use this. Please use the -A option and provide it from a text file.  if you do this to run a script use +s from chmod on the script

Comment: @Rinzwind where in `ps -ef`, I tried my command, but couldn't find password in `ps -ef`

Comment: The echo will show it. It will be brief but it will be  shown. You need a 2nd terminal where you have ps -ef | grep echo running permanently

Comment: @Ravexina which Ubuntu version are you running? I tried this command on my friend's pc running Ubuntu 18.04, I couldn't reproduce it. I think this output can only be reproduced in Ubuntu 20.04. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 myself, I also tried this on a bootable pendrive with Ubuntu 20.04, I get the same error. Now I think it's related to Ubuntu version

Comment: I get the same result as you on Lubuntu 20.04

Comment: @AkashKarnatak I'm on Debian right now. Bash 5.0.3. I've got an half configured Ubuntu 20.04 I'll try to test it there an keep you informed.

Comment: What if `Sorry, try again.` was actually printed on  `/dev/tty` . Though I couldn't find any answer on internet to redirect output from `/dev/tty` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @AkashKarnatak same for me on Ubuntu 20.04. I'll keep you updated if I was able to find anything further.

Comment: @Rinzwind what if I use this command instead, 
`sudo -S true <<< "password"`?

Comment: same. That is just another way of redirecting. You need to supply the password from a file.

Comment: but this won't be listed in `ps -ef` i guess

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm guessing that it's a bug in `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
script -qec "echo foo | sudo -S ls > /dev/null 2>/dev/null " > /dev/null
```

Keep in mind there are security concerns if you wish to pass password as an argument to your script, or store it in a script file.